# Why is my animation state is being shared across component instances?

Tags: angular, typescript, carousel, angular-animations

Whenever you interact with one call of the carousel (i.e. clicking next or prev) the animation plays for both instances of the component. What is wrong here?

carousel.component.ts

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-carousel',
 standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  imports:[ CommonModule ],
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.scss'],
  animations: [ CarouselAnimation ]
})
export class CarouselComponent {
  @Input() items: string[] = [];
  @Input() itemsPerSlide: number = 0;
  @Input() carouselName:string = "";
  currentIndex: number = 0;
  hasNextItems: boolean = true;

  get groupedItems(): string[][] {
    const result: string[][] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i += this.itemsPerSlide) {
      result.push(this.items.slice(i, i + this.itemsPerSlide));
    }
    return result;
  }

  next() {
    const nextIndex = (this.currentIndex + 1) % this.groupedItems.length;
    this.hasNextItems = this.groupedItems[nextIndex].length > 0;
    if (this.hasNextItems) {
      this.currentIndex = nextIndex;
    }
  }

  prev() {
    const prevIndex = (this.currentIndex - 1 + this.groupedItems.length) % this.groupedItems.length;
    const prevItemsPerSlide = this.groupedItems[prevIndex].length;

    if (prevItemsPerSlide > 0) {
      this.hasNextItems = true;
      this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex - 1 + this.groupedItems.length) % this.groupedItems.length;
    }
  }
}
```

carousel.component.html

```
<div id="DynamicCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div *ngFor="let itemGroup of groupedItems; let i = index" [class.active]="i === currentIndex" class="carousel-item"  [@fadeInOut]>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
        <div *ngFor="let item of itemGroup" class="carousel-inner-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" [src]="item" alt="Slide {{i + 1}}">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-prev" href="#DynamicCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" (click)="prev()">
    <div class="icon-container">
      <i class="fa fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-next" href="#DynamicCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" (click)="next()">
    <div class="icon-container">
      <i class="fa fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

animations.ts

```
export const CarouselAnimation = [
  trigger('fadeInOut', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: 0 }),
      animate('300ms ease-in', style({ opacity: 1 }))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate('300ms ease-out', style({ opacity: 0 }))
    ])
  ])
]
```

Usage

```
<h2>Carousel</h2>
<app-carousel [items]="carouselItems" [itemsPerSlide]="3" [carouselName]="'Carousel'"></app-carousel>
<h2>Carousel2</h2>
<app-carousel [items]="carouselItems2" [itemsPerSlide]="3" [carouselName]="'Carousel2'"></app-carousel>
```

carousel item arrays:

```
  carouselItems: string[] = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
  ];
  carouselItems2: string[] = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
  ];
```

- Tried to change the trigger name to be independant.
- Tried making the id unique.
- Even tried duplicating the code (gross)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have problems with change detection understanding.

On any interaction with your components there is new `groupedItems` created which causes elements to be recreated and thus re:enter the dom = play animation.

To eliminate the bug you can add `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` so change detection won't trigger in the carousel that was not touched

```
@Component({
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

Comment: This was indeed the issue! Thank you - I will read up more on change detection.